# List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, list

I get error when LargestRevision list has null revision numbers. Here revision number is a number field and Quote_Link__c is a lookup.

```
  if(quoteLink.Id!=null)
       {
        LargestRevision =[SELECT Revision_Number__c,Quote_Link__c FROM OPP_QuoteLink__c WHERE Quote_Link__c=:quoteLink.Id ORDER BY Revision_Number__c DESC LIMIT 1];      
            if(LargestRevision.size()==0&&LargestRevision[0].Revision_Number__c==null)
            {
                //System.debug('--LargestRevisionsize---'+LargestRevision.size());
                //System.debug('--LargestRevision[0]---'+LargestRevision[0].Revision_Number__c); 
                clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c = quoteLink.Id;
                clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c = 1;
                System.debug('--clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c ---'+clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c);
            }
       }
        else{
                System.debug('---quoteLink.Quote_Link__c---'+quoteLink.Quote_Link__c);                
                clonedQuteLink.Quote_Link__c = quoteLink.Quote_Link__c;
                clonedQuteLink.Revision_Number__c=(LargestRevision[0].Revision_Number__c)+1;    //THIS line throws error if list has revision null
        }
```

Comment: How do you init the `LargestRevision` variable? You can not use the index when a list is empty.

Comment: Its a list of objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If largestrevision has a size of zero, it is empty. You can only access indices less than size. You probably meant to use || instead of &&. The shortcut operator will only evaluate the right-hand side if the left side is true. This will prevent the index exception.

Comment: Turned out to a silly issue. I was looking into an index even if there was no value. I guess i have to improve knowledge on condional statements. Thanks for helping @sdfcfox